# Spark Streaming job fails with ReceiverDisconnectedException Class

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

I've Spark Streaming job which captures the near real time data from Azure Eventhub and runs 24/7.
More interestingly, my job fails at least 2 times a day with the below error. if I google the error, Microsoft docs gives me **'This exception is thrown if two or more PartitionReceiver instances connect to the same partition with different epoch values'**. I'm not worried about data loss because spark Checkpointing will automatically take care of data when i restart the job, but my question is why the spark streaming job fails 2-3 times a day with the same error.

Has anybody faced the same issue, is there any solution/workaround available of this. Any help would be much appreciated.

error: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown if two or more **Partitions Receiver** instances connect to the same partition with different epoch values.

What is Partition Receiver?

This is a logical representation of receiving from a EventHub partition.

A PartitionReceiver is tied to a ConsumerGroup + Partition combination. If you are creating an epoch based PartitionReceiver (i.e. PartitionReceiver.Epoch != 0) you cannot have more than one active receiver per ConsumerGroup + Partition combo. You can have multiple receivers per ConsumerGroup + Partition combination with non-epoch receivers.

It sounds like you are running two instances of the application, two concurrent classes, or two applications that use the same event hub consumer group. Event hub consumer groups are effectively pointers to a point in time on the event stream. If you try and use one consumer group pointing with two instances of code, then you get a conflict like the one you are seeing.

**Either:**

1. Ensure you only have a single instance reading the consumer group at a time.
2. Use two consumer groups when you need two separate programs or sets of functionality to process the event hub at the same time.
3. If you are looking to parallelize for performance, look in to event hub Partitioning and how to take advantage of processing each partition independently.

There is also an alternative scenario where an event hub partition is switched over to another host as part of the event hub's internal load balancing. In this case you may see the error you are receiving. In this case, just log it and continue on.

For more details, refer "[Features and terminology in Azure Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features)" and "[Event Hubs Receiver Epoch](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/gyan/2014/09/02/event-hubs-receiver-epoch/)".

Hope this helps.